# Xamarin, MVVMCross and crashreporting

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, crash-reports

I am looking for a plugin/component to crashreporting (preferably free) for an app which should be published only on AppStore (so it's made ​​with MVVMCross but the target is iOS only).

I used Raygun.io is very valuable as a tool but the cost is pretty important.

Would be interesting to understand how to manage the project Core (MVVMCross) in order to well integrate with a crashreporting system. I should remove all catches that i'd like to do reporting?

**Resume:**

- What are the best free tools easily fit into Xamarin and MVVMCross crashreporting to do?
- Once selected tool, how it should be handled in Core project?

Comment: Tried TestFlight? It has crash reporting support. I am using TestFlight until Crashlytics rolls out Xamarin support. And I doubt you can handle this in Core. Crash Reporting will need to be done on Platform level (its a single or very few lines of code anyways) :)

Comment: I have tested TestFlight. Configured as here https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/TestFlight/sample/TestFlightSample/AppDelegate.cs it reports me crash only if i download app from TestFlight and not from AppStore. How could i set up to have crash reporting over to ad hoc release (TestFligt) in AppStore?

Comment: I haven't tried personally, but TestFlight builds are production ready only different being the data is sent to FlightPath. Check this http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829571-does-the-sdk-support-production-builds-

Comment: Good tip! I'll wait an invitation :-)

Answer (score 2):

use free [Xamarin.Insights](https://insights.xamarin.com). It is the official error reporting and crash analytics tool by Xamarin.

Comment: Now HockeyApp will become the official Xamarin Tool: https://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2016/04/27/evolve-2016.html